# 連続置換の場合にBoost.RegexとOnigmoを混在させる書き方は可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

普通の
document.selection.Replace("","",eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);

このような書き方では混在できたのですが以下のような一発でバルクインサートする場合は混在可能でしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

batch_list = editor.filters;
Boost.Regexの正規表現
Onigmoの正規表現
document.selection.BatchReplace(batch_list,eeReplaceAll,0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら、`BatchReplace` メソッド内で、複数の正規表現エンジンを混在させることはできません。問題の回避方法としては `BatchReplace` メソッドを複数回の行に分けて、`eeExFindRegexBoost` または `eeExFindRegexOnigmo` を指定することで、ご希望の動作と同等の動作になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一旦区切ると言うことになりますでしょうか？切替のときは一度document.selection.BatchReplace(batch_list,eeReplaceAll,0);で閉じてbatch_list = editor.filters;から書いて閉じると言うことになりますでしょうか？こういうことでしたらなるべく避けたいので汎用性が強い方に絞りたいです。推測ではOnigmoのほうが{Hiragana}などで日本語には優れているがBoost.Regexのほうが先に仕様だったために前に作られたマクロの互換性優先でBoost.Regexをデフォルトにしているということになりますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: はい。日本語のためだけではないですが、Onigmoのほうが多くの機能がありますが、前に作られたマクロの互換性優先でBoost.Regexを既定にしているということになります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。理解いたしました｡他の件なんですが、頻度の高い質問で承認と▲マークを同時に押すとサクラと思われて評価が取り消しになるようですので全部消されると元も子もないので今後は承認マークのみにさせていただきます。よろしくお願いいたします。